# Should I choose mongo aggregation or should do it at application level service

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the below collections.

> Company:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7848e8ca70273218e9d743"),
"name" : "Google",
"departments" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "IT",
        "_id" : "1234567890"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Sales",
        "_id" : "1234567891"
    }
]
}
```

> User:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a784977ca70273218e9d759"),
    "name" : "Sankarshan",
    "company" : ObjectId("5a7848e8ca70273218e9d743"),
    "department" : "1234567890"
}
```

> topicCategories

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
"name" : "topicCtegoryOne",
"order" : 1
}
```

> topics

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
"topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
"name" : "TopicOne",
"order" : 1,
"label" : "oneTopic",
"color" : "red"
}
```

> dimentions

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a784fdcca70273218e9d869"),
"name" : "dimentionOne"
}
```

> queries

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a78519aca70273218e9d8d7"),
"topic" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
"dimention" : ObjectId("5a784fdcca70273218e9d869"),
"order" : 1,
"label" : "queryLabelOne",
"statement" : "This is one question - Top1"
}
```

> User_responses

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7859f5ca70273218e9da7d"),
"user" : ObjectId("5a784977ca70273218e9d759"),
"company" : ObjectId("5a7848e8ca70273218e9d743"),
"department" : "1234567890",
"response" : {
    "question" : ObjectId("5a78519aca70273218e9d8d7"),
    "topic" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
    "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
    "dimention" : ObjectId("5a784fdcca70273218e9d869"),
    "rating" : 5,
    "color" : "red"
}
}
```

> What is happening above

1. Each User belongs to a company.
2. Each Topic belongs to a Topic category.
3. Each Query belongs to a Topic
4. Each query has a dimention.
5. A user can answer a Query in terms of rating.
6. The user response to each question will be stored in User_responses.

> What I want to achieve

An aggregated result of responses based on **Topic category** and **Dimension**

> Expected aggregated result format

1. The query is based on one topic category.
2. All questions on each topic is aggregated based on Topic
3. Each Topic will have calculated average ratings based on dimension.

> Response

```
{
"topicCategory": "topic category",
"topics": [
    {
        "topicLabel": "label of the topic one",
        "dimentions": [
            {
                "name": "dimention name one",
                "avgValue": 5.6
            }
            {
                "name": "dimention name two",
                "avgValue": 4.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "topicLabel": "label of the topic two",
        "dimentions": [
            {
                "name": "dimention name one",
                "avgValue": 6.6
            }
            {
                "name": "dimention name two",
                "avgValue": 9.5
            }
        ]
    }

]   
}
```

**Can I implement this using Mongo aggregation or should I do it at service level?**

> What I have tried doing

```
db.getCollection('collResp').aggregate([
{
    $match: 
    { 
        company: ObjectId("5a7848e8ca70273218e9d743"),
        department: "1234567890"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            topic: "$response.topic",
            category: "$response.topicCategory"
        },
        responses: {
            $push: "$response"
        }
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'topics',
        localField: '_id.topic',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: "topic"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$topic"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'topicCategories',
        localField: '_id.category',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: "category"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$category"
    }
}
])
```

> What I got

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
    "topic" : ObjectId("5a78512cca70273218e9d8bd"),
    "category" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f")
},
"responses" : [ 
    {
        "question" : ObjectId("5a7851a6ca70273218e9d8d9"),
        "topic" : ObjectId("5a78512cca70273218e9d8bd"),
        "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
        "dimention" : ObjectId("5a784fdcca70273218e9d869"),
        "rating" : 8,
        "color" : "red"
    }, 
    {
        "question" : ObjectId("5a78580eca70273218e9da10"),
        "topic" : ObjectId("5a78512cca70273218e9d8bd"),
        "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
        "dimention" : ObjectId("5a7851d5ca70273218e9d8ee"),
        "rating" : 7,
        "color" : "red"
    }
],
"topic" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a78512cca70273218e9d8bd"),
    "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
    "name" : "TopicTwo",
    "order" : 2,
    "label" : "twoTopic",
    "color" : "green"
},
"category" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
    "name" : "topicCtegoryOne",
    "order" : 1
}
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
    "topic" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
    "category" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f")
},
"responses" : [ 
    {
        "question" : ObjectId("5a78519aca70273218e9d8d7"),
        "topic" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
        "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
        "dimention" : ObjectId("5a784fdcca70273218e9d869"),
        "rating" : 5,
        "color" : "red"
    }, 
    {
        "question" : ObjectId("5a785807ca70273218e9da0e"),
        "topic" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
        "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
        "dimention" : ObjectId("5a7851d5ca70273218e9d8ee"),
        "rating" : 3,
        "color" : "red"
    }
],
"topic" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a784cc3ca70273218e9d7d3"),
    "topicCategory" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
    "name" : "TopicOne",
    "order" : 1,
    "label" : "oneTopic",
    "color" : "red"
},
"category" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a784a10ca70273218e9d76f"),
    "name" : "topicCtegoryOne",
    "order" : 1
}
}
```

> What more is required

- Each response had a question. And each question has a dimention
- I need to get average rating based on dimention.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you like to pass `Topic Category` and `Dimension` ids as an input? if so, where `company` collection may be used?

Comment: I think you Should Use aggregation only, with limited Fields Projecting.

Comment: @styopdev `Topic category id` is an input but `Dimension` needs to be fetched from the question in each response.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I am able to group results based on topics and I am able to get responses related to a topic as an array. Now how can I produce averages based on the dimension of the question in the response. I am struck here.

Comment: probably you should use $group operator for that, it would be more clear if you add your current query to the question.

Comment: @styopdev I just updated my question with the query and the output I am getting